# How to modify NodeJS built-in global objects?

Tags: node.js, global

I'd like to add an important functionality that I can use at work without using require() every time. So, I thought modifying built-in objects can make this happen but I could not locate the locations of those objects to do the modification.

Are those objects in NodeJS binary? Would that mean I have to fork the whole NodeJS repo to make this happen?

Please, I don't want to use prototype editing etc which are same as require. I need to have native feeling.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to avoid typing `require` and at the expense of making the code non-portable.

Comment: @Mark Meyer I don't mind.

Comment: What kind of functionality are you looking to add? If it is allowing functions to be accessible from elsewhere in the same NodeJS process, you should be able to add them as properties on the `global` object in your entry point of your application.

Comment: @abondoa That one I already knew but never felt native. I just want it globally for every application I create on Node. Functionality can be anything.  I'm looking  for straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I agree with an earlier comment that this sounds like a bit of an XY problem where we could better help you if you describe what problem you're really trying to solve.  Portable node.js programs that work anywhere or work with any future versions of node.js don't rely on some sort of custom configured environment in order to run.  They use the built-in capabilities of node.js and they require/import in external things they want to add to the environment.

---

> Are those objects in NodeJS binary?

Yes, they are in the executable.

> Would that mean I have to fork the whole NodeJS repo to make this happen?

Yes.

> Please, I don't want to use prototype editing etc which are same as require. I need to have native feeling.

"Native feeling"?  This sounds like you haven't really bought into the node.js module architecture.  It is different than many other environments.  It's easy to get used to over time.  IMO, it would really be better to go with the flow and architecture of the platform rather than make some custom version of node.js just to save one line of typing in your startup code.

And, the whole concept of adding a number of globals you can use anywhere pretty much shows that you haven't fully understood the design, architectural, code reuse and testability advantages of the module design baked into node.js.  If you had, you wouldn't be trying to write a lot of code that can't be reused in other ways that you don't anticipate now.

---

That said, in searching through the node.js source code on Github, I found this source file [node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/ec0dd6fa1cfa03b3983419acedb27ef95d297c82/lib/internal/bootstrap/node.js#L51) which is where lots of things are added to the node.js global object such as `setTimeout()`, `clearTimeout()`, `setImmediate()`, `clearImmediate()` and so on.  So, that source file seems to be where node.js is setting up the global object.  If you wanted to add your own things there, that's one place where it would be done.

To provide a sample of that code (you can see the link above for the complete code):

```
if (!config.noBrowserGlobals) {
  // Override global console from the one provided by the VM
  // to the one implemented by Node.js
  // https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#console-namespace
  exposeNamespace(global, 'console', createGlobalConsole(global.console));

  const { URL, URLSearchParams } = require('internal/url');
  // https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url
  exposeInterface(global, 'URL', URL);
  // https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlsearchparams
  exposeInterface(global, 'URLSearchParams', URLSearchParams);

  const {
    TextEncoder, TextDecoder
  } = require('internal/encoding');
  // https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#textencoder
  exposeInterface(global, 'TextEncoder', TextEncoder);
  // https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#textdecoder
  exposeInterface(global, 'TextDecoder', TextDecoder);

  // https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#windoworworkerglobalscope
  const timers = require('timers');
  defineOperation(global, 'clearInterval', timers.clearInterval);
  defineOperation(global, 'clearTimeout', timers.clearTimeout);
  defineOperation(global, 'setInterval', timers.setInterval);
  defineOperation(global, 'setTimeout', timers.setTimeout);

  defineOperation(global, 'queueMicrotask', queueMicrotask);

  // Non-standard extensions:
  defineOperation(global, 'clearImmediate', timers.clearImmediate);
  defineOperation(global, 'setImmediate', timers.setImmediate);
}
```

This code is built into the node.js executable so the only way I know of to directly modify it (without hackish patching of the executable itself) would be to modify the file and then rebuild node.js for your platform into a custom build.

---

On a little more practical note, you can also use the `-r module` [command line argument](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_r_require_module) to tell node.js to run `require(module)` before starting your main script.  So, you could make a different way of starting node.js from a shell file that always passes the `-r fullPathToYourModule` argument to node.js so it will always run your startup module that adds things to the global object.

Again, you'd be doing this just to save one line of typing in your startup file.  It is really worth doing that?

Comment: @sqlbie - It's not absurd.  Adding one global that your code depends upon makes ZERO of your modules that use that global independently reusable.  Now, they all depend upon that global already being there in your custom environment.  Whereas, if you add ONE line of code to those modules to load in a shared module that manages that one variable, then they can ALL be reusable.  That's the nodejs design concept you are blowing off.

Comment: @sqlbie - Also, you say one global now, but if you don't learn the non-global ways of doing it and get used to doing it that way, then over time a project ends up with lots of globals.  There are legit reasons for having zero globals in your project.  It appears you do not appreciate those reasons.  That is my point.

Comment: I already knew non-global ways of doing it but they don't fit my needs. I use the function daily basis and hate using Require. It's built-in function and cause no harm for other applications for adding the feature I want. You won't need built-in language features if you think this way. Whether you care not, It helps my productivity.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that they are in binary. I will go ahead and fork Node.

Comment: @sqlbie - Just curious, are you going to merge your fork every time there's a major bug fix or feature release of node.js or just stay with your forked version for years?  I guess if you're just modifying that one file, a merge wouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: I stay in LTS and merge when time comes.

Comment: @sqlbie - Just to be clear here, do you realize that adding one `require()` statement to your startup file, can add that global for you and remove the need for a fork?  That's still not the modular way to do it, but it gets you your global.